# Backslash escaped characters in JavaCC token

Tags: javacc

I'm writing [JavaCC](http://javacc.org/) parser for a character stream like this

`Abc \(Def\) Gh (Ij; Kl); Mno (Pqr)`

and should get it [tokenized](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc1.3) like this

1. Abc \(Def\) Gh
2. LPAREN
3. Ij
4. SEMICOLON
5. Kl
6. RPAREN
7. SEMICOLON
8. Mno
9. LPAREN
10. Pqr
11. RPAREN

The current token definition is

```
TOKEN:
{
  < WORDCHAR : (~[";", "(", ")"])+ >
   |  <LPAREN: "(">
   |  <RPAREN: ")">
   |  <SEMICOLON: ";">
}
```

How should I change the WORDCHAR token to include backslash escaped parentheses but not parentheses without leading backslash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TOKEN:
{
  < WORDCHAR : (~[";", "(", ")"] | "\\(" | "\\)")+ >
   |  <LPAREN: "(">
   |  <RPAREN: ")">
   |  <SEMICOLON: ";">
}
```

Comment: Adding `| "\\(" | "\\)"` to WORDCHAR token definition did the trick.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the original poster's question.  And there is nothing wrong with this answer. The question was "How should I change the WORDCHAR token to include backslash escaped parentheses but not parentheses without leading backslash?" and this answer answers that question precisely.  Had the OP asked why their code didn't work, then that would be a different matter; but it's perfectly obvious why the original didn't work -- it didn't mention any backslashes. To find out why the answer code works, anyone can read the documentation.